# GraphQL Schema - how to represent (and query) a hierarchical structure

Tags: graphql

I am using GraphQL to build a "proof of concept" service.

One of the objects I am modelling in the Schema, is an Organisation's structure. Typically, an organisational structure is hierarchical, and different nodes could have different number of child nodes etc.

Typically, an org chart looks a bit like this:

```
                  CEO
                   |
   ----------------------------------
   |                 |              |
  Tech Team    Middle Management   ...
```

I a sure this is a problem that has been solved several times, in GraphQL applications - however, I can't seem to find any documentation that shows how to represent a hierarchical structure (such as an org. chart), using GraphQL

```
type Organisation {
   # Root Node here ...
}
```

How can a hierarchical structure be represented in a GraphQL Schema?

Answer (score 2):

A type can refer to itself. In your case an employee can have a *supervisor* (except for the CEO who has none) and can also optionally have staff.

```
type Employee {
  id: ID!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  supervisor: Employee
  staff: [Employee]
}
```

Comment: Thanks @MichaelFloyd. I kinda worked this out by myself, in the end! What about if I want to make a generic `TreeNode` object (so I can represent several different hierarchical structures). I know `interfaces` exist in GraphQL. But how would I (for instance), use `interface TreeNode { id: ID!  parent: TreeNode children: [TreeNode]! } ` to declare type `Employee`?

Comment: That's a good, but different question ;)